# Help understanding Attempting to create AWDL interface for en0 in wifi logs

Tags: mac, network, wifi

Came across a wifi log today titled wifi-01-06-2021__(the date it was created). I have never seen one of this type before, and I am pretty confused about the first few lines of it:

```
SC: <airport[237]> scInitInterface for device en0
<airport[237]> _bsdDriver_init: registration for monitoring bssSteeringRequest event
Info: <airport[237]> psCallback: powerSource = AC Power
Info: <airport[237]> psCallback: set powersave disabled on en0 Roam: <airport[237]> _initInterface: AirPort Interface <en0> <6>
P2P: <airport[237]> CreateVirtualInterface: Attempting to create AWDL interface for en0 with MAC address *omitted* (attemptNumber = 0)
P2P: <airport[237]> CreateVirtualInterface: Created AWDL interface awdl0 with address *omitted* for en0
Offload: <airport[237]> _openIpAddressMonitoringSockets: Monitoring IP address changes on en0
<airport[237]> _initLocaleManager: Started locale manager
<airport[237]> _initInterface: Failed to query current SSID (Operation not supported)
<airport[237]> CoreCapture preference: 0
<airport[237]> finished with CoreCapture preferences
```

I know AWDL is the Apple Wireless Direct Link, and is used for peer-to-peer, and en0 is my wifi. What I don't understand is what it means by creating a virtual interface, or the MAC address that I have omitted.

Bluetooth and all sharing are disabled, and when this happened, wifi was disabled to. I wasn't connected to a network. The MAC address in question doesn't seem to match anything I can find on my Mac, or on my network, though that should be irrelevant given I wasn't connected to it.

Is this just a random MAC address my Mac is generating using MAC randomisation, or what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a virtual interface just means that the computer internally refers to something by one name which is really physically backed by something with a different name.

For example you might have a physical Ethernet interface in your computer, and then you create a virtual interface for a VPN connection. The data is really transferred over the physical interface, but you refer to the virtual name so that the system knows that the data destined there is going to be encrypted and encapsulated before being sent on the physical network.

The AWDL interface you have logged here could have been used for for example AirDrop, AirPlay or some form of Continuity. It is for example possible to AirDrop and AirPlay without being connected to an existing, specific WiFi network. Instead a direct connection is created using an Apple protocol over this “virtual interface”.

Regarding the creation of the MAC address - this is not something you should worry about. It is perfectly normal for macOS to create randomized MAC addresses in order to prevent you from being unwillingly tracked by others.

You can read more about where and when Apple employs MAC randomisation [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secb9cb3140c/web).

You can distinguish such a locally generated, randomised MAC because the 2nd least significant bit of the first byte is a one. This means that the MAC address is locally generated, and as such holds no intrinsic "meaning". If you look at the hexadecimal representation of a MAC address, this means that the second character of the address must be either 2, 6, A or E for an ordinary WiFi interface. An interface used for multicasting can have a 3, 7, B or F instead.

This is different from MACs that have the 2nd least significant bit of the first byte set to one. Those MAC addresses starts with a vendor ID that allows you to lookup whom manufactured the hardware. The second character of the hexadecimal representation of the address then is either 0, 4, 8 or C for a unicast MAC, and 1, 5, 9 or D for multicasting.

You did not include the actual MAC address you see on your system, as it was redacted from your logs - but you can check with the above mentioned system whether or not the MAC address you're seeing is actually a randomised, locally generated one or not.

The other part you were concerned about was not being able to find the interface in the list of interface you find with `ifconfig`. You can generate a full list of interfaces using this command:

```
ifconfig -l
```

You'll find the `awdl0` interface in there. As indicated in your comments, you had a concern that this listing did not show the same MAC address as your log snippet. This is actually not a problem and completely normal.

The MAC address listed by ifconfig is typically the physical MAC. In practice it is often an address stored in an EEPROM chip on network interface during manufacturing. Note that the contents of an EEPROM can be changed, so it is still something that can be changed, if you would like.

However, MAC address randomisation happens quite often (i.e. often when you connect to a new network SSID, every 24 hours or similar). For this purpose it doesn't make sense to change the "burned in" value in the EEPROM. Also your system can actually be using multiple randomised MAC addresses at the same time (for example if you're connecting to an infrastructure access point at the same time AirDrop'ping while AirPlay'ing).

The actual MAC address randomisation thus happens on a slightly different layer. It is so that when a packet goes out on the network, the operating system can typically with most types of interfaces completely decide which MAC address is listed in the header - it doesn't have to be the physical address.

This means that it is perfectly normal for ifconfig to show one MAC address while a different MAC address is actually using for packets going out on the `awdl0` interface - and thus also for logging `awdl0` related debug messages.

Indeed if you look closer at the ifconfig interface list, you'll typically also find an interface named `llw0`. This is the low-latency WiFi interface - a virtual interface similar to the `awdl0` interface. It will show the same MAC address as the `awdl0` interface, as it the physical MAC of the WiFi interface that is shown. MAC address randomisation for `awdl0` does not apply to `llw0`, so they can communicate with different MAC addresses at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So despite ADWL existing as an interface in adwl0, it still created a virutal interface on en0, and it would do this even if I have airplay disabled (more specifically wifi and bluetooth disabled, which is pretty much the same thing)? Is it possible to list the interfaces created in this manner, as ifconfig doesn't seem to?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood something. The awdl interface did not exist before it was created, that doesn’t make sense. Disabling WiFi is definitely not the same as disabling AirPlay, no. Use “ifconfig -l” to list the interfaces.

Comment: I think I may be. When I list all my interfaces, its shows awdl0 as one. However, it doesn't list the same MAC address as the one shown in the logs when it was created despite the shared name of awdl0.

Comment: Let’s tackle this from a different angle: Why are you looking into this? Are you concerned about something? Is there something not working for you?

Comment: All of this is perfectly normal. MAC addresses do change. AirPlay can work even though you’re not connected to a WIFi network.

Comment: I am only concerned insofar as I don't understand why, anytime I look at this log, the MAC address it creates for the awdl0 interface on en0 is different every reboot, yet the one I can see for awdl0 when I use ifconfig remains the same.

Comment: And why is that a concern to you? I don't see the problem - but perhaps you're experiencing some problem with using the functionality, or what is the reason you're looking into this?

Comment: Ok maybe concerned isn't the right word. Confused is better. I am confused as to why, in my logs, it gives one mac address, but ifconfig returns another. As for why I am looking into it? I like to know what my mac is or is not doing.

Comment: Yeah just checked virtual interaces in System Preferences-Network. Only bridge0 is coming up.

Comment: Okay, it is actually quite simple: The two do not need to match. That ifconfig lists a MAC does not necessarily mean that packets sent out on that interface uses that MAC address in the header. The system and its programs are free to use to other addresses. Ifconfig usually lists the hardware MAC address (which is often also setable). If you are afraid your Mac is doing something “bad”, then don’t worry anymore.

Comment: It’s fully OK that only bridge0 appears. That is not the indication of a problem.

Comment: Ah ok, so when it says its creating a virtual interface, thats the MAC address it would likely use for communication, different from the actual one that will appear using ifconfig?

Comment: You have not included the MAC addresses in your post for some reason, so you'll have to check yourself if the MAC address matches the one given by ifconfig or not. You'll probably find that they're different, and this is not a problem at all. There's no indication anywhere in this log that anything is "wrong".

Comment: So for example, the one appearing in my logs for the virtual interface on en0 for awdl0 is 16:e9:cg:e8:1e:1f. So taking the first byte, the second least significant bit is a 1, so it is a randomised address. But its normal that this will not match the awdl0 address that ifconfig returns,  ca:7d:ef:c4:61:ec. Thought I think it's also randomly generated as well?

Comment: Yes, both MAC addresses are normal. There's nothing to be worried about.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but if awdl0 is already randomised, then how come when the other virtual interface is created for it on en0, it doesn't use the same MAC address if its already been randomised?

Comment: I don't know how technical you are, as the details will be a bit complicated, if you're not a programmer or similar. Be assured that this is perfectly normal, and does not represent any type of problem whatsoever. The technical explanation: The term "virtual interface" is a generic, abstract term that does not specify a concrete implementation. The type of "virtual interface" that the log file talks about is not necessarily the same type of "virtual interface" that ifconfig logs. The log file talking about "creating an interface", does not necessarily mean that it actually asks the [...]

Comment: [...] operating system to "create" such an interface (which is basically just a small data structure in memory - it is not a physical thing at all). It merely means that the representation of such an interface is created (i.e. "setup") within the program. In practice, if the awdl0 interface is non-existing on a OS level, then it would be created - but if it is already there, nothing more happens at the OS-level. Interfaces are made to be consumed by multiple programs at once. The needs and concerns of one program might not be the same as the needs and concerns of other concurrent programs[...]

Comment: This particular consumer wants and needs MAC randomisation, so at one point or another it needs to pick that random address. The log message just tells you that it has picked such an address. It is merely a debug or informational message that is not at all an indication of anything being "wrong". The program now "remembers" (i.e. it is stored in RAM) this address, so that when it sends out packets on the network, it sets the sender MAC to this address. At the same time other programs can be using the awdl0 interface for sending packets, and they might have the requirement that the [...]

Comment: MAC is identical to the one known by the operating system, so they send out packets without specifying a specific MAC address, and the OS supplies the address that ifconfig can list for you. As for why this particular program does not recognize that the MAC address is already randomised (and obviously does other checks, such as determining that it is randomed at the same intervals that it requires, and that the address is not used for other purposes that could somehow enable unintentional tracking through other means) in order to avoid making up a new random MAC - that is just how Apple [...]

Comment: [...] choose to do it. The extra "cost" in terms of performance of performing an "extra" ("unnecessary") randomisation is extremely small. Having to perform those checks in order to avoid it adds a lot of complexity and possibility of things going wrong. It is a perfectly valid choice to do one over the other - it does not indicate any kind of "bad programming", "resource wastefulness" or the likes. Modern computers are filled with these types of decisions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply.So Airport is creating a virtual interface for peer-to-peer using awdl0 on en0, that has it's own random address instead of the random one of awdl0, but this virtual interface doesn't actually use p2p0, which I have seen in other posts, which can also appear in ifconfig? Or has peer-to-peer using awdl0 replaced p2p0?

Comment: I don’t understand why you’re bringing p2p0 into this now? It hasn’t been mentioned here before. Is there some real question, project or task that you’re trying to accomplish that you haven’t revealed yet? If so, it is much easier to give you the relevant information when we know why you’re asking. The p2p0 interface is for Apple’s peer-to-peer wireless protocol (which is the name for a specific protocol, and here not used in as the generic term peer to peer). It is not the same protocol as AWDL.

Comment: Basically macOS uses awdl0 to talk the AWDL protocol with other AWDL-speaking devices, and similarly uses p2p0 to talk the AP2P protocol with other AP2P-speaking devices. AWDL is newer than AP2P, but if you want to speak to a AP2P device you need to speak AP2P, you cannot just use AWDL because it’s newer or better. Both ends have to be compatible.

Comment: Apologies. I just saw the P2P in the part of the log I posted, and had initially assumed it was related to p2p0, which is why I thought the addresses didn't match. My overall question was simply regarding those two entries in the part I posted. Why AWDL was being created on en0, but with a different address than what I could list, and why it mentioned peer-to-peer, yet wasn't using p2p0. I assume then it's just what the log had affixed.

Answer (score 1):

Apple AWDL is a proprietary undocumented IEEE 802.11 based ad hoc protocol. Apple uses it for Airdrop and AirPlay <strike>and perhaps even FindMy AirTag tracking</strike> (uses UWB radio not AWDL virtual interface). When you see the virtual AWDL0 interface that is what it is doing. Apple products are peer-to-peer talking to each other using this protocol.

If you are interested, there's a fascinating paper written by a few researchers who reverse engineered things in 2018 and documented their findings. I found that one of the co-authors of this paper posted the link to Stack Exchange previously.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.03156

Virtual interfaces typically change MAC / Physical Addresses when they are created. That's why the Physical Address (MAC) changes all the time.  I have an AWDL0 interface on my Mac that's not currently connected to anything but its there with a unique Physical Address (MAC).  Same thing happens with most VPN virtual interfaces. The Physical Address (MAC) is generated on the fly because the device is not actually a physical device. You can actually change your Physical Address (MAC) if you wish to. It's called MAC Address Spoofing.

Change the address to aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff for en0 interface:

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

Set a random physical address:

```
openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//' | xargs sudo ifconfig en0 ether
```

Virtual interfaces change Physical Addresses (MAC) all the time. They would do it via programming code and not so much a command line ifconfig entry.

**Addition:** Not suggesting one should change their Physical Address (MAC) just that you can indeed change it.  Yes, Apple has been randomizing the Physical Address (MAC) as of late.  That was done for security reasons on iOS devices especially but also Macs. Apparently, Edward Snowden claimed the NSA was tracking movement of mobile devices via the MAC address. Other companies started randomizing their MAC Addresses as a result. Google has been doing it with Android since 6.0. Windows 10 and even Linux kernel 3.18 and above.

Changing a Physical Address (MAC) can cause confusion as the first three bytes (6 characters) defines the manufacturer. This could potentially cause an employer's IT security to become concerned and block a device from the corporate network.

Sometimes a Physical Address (MAC) might be hardcoded to a particular system and changing it can break connectivity. But this is a small edge case scenario.

Comment: Just wanted to add a few smaller things to this: AirTag do not use the AWDL protocol at all (they are not WiFi devices). Also it is not so that just because an interface is virtual, it must change MAC address all the time. Many types of virtual interfaces have a set address when it is created, and that's it - it doesn't change again during its lifetime. Ofcourse you can change any MAC at any time, but it is not usual to do so for many types of virtual interfaces. It is actually quite recent that Apple started doing MAC randomisation on WiFi interfaces on the Mac.

Comment: Another thing: It is not in general a good idea to just use a random MAC address. If you want to follow the standards, the 7th bit of the first byte should be a 1. This indicates that the address was generated locally. If you look at the random MAC that Apple generates, they also follow this principle.

Comment: Adjusted answer based on comment feedback.

Comment: Sorry to be a nuisance - but the edited answer is actually a bit inaccurate. As I just mentioned in my other comment, the 7th bit of the first byte is a 1 when it is randomised address on an Apple system (and should be on other vendor's systems as well). This means that the first three bytes do _not_ define the manufacturer. That is only the case if that bit is set as 0.